# Shiny: calculating standard deviation from an uploaded excel file

Tags: r, excel, shiny

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation of an Excel file loaded onto my Shiny App. I don't appear to be able to do so. When I put sd(output$contents) or sd(file1) it tends to crash the application. Here is what I have so far

For reference, the data I am uploading is univariate time series
I would be very grateful if someone would be able to help me out- I think it is a beginner problem! perhaps I am just viewing the file and not using it?

EDIT: the excel file always contains a single column of numbers, but the title and header may change. Therefore I would like to reference column A in the changing excel files.

```
  ui <- fluidPage(
    setBackgroundColor("ghostwhite"),
    titlePanel(h1("title", style = "color:navy")),
    p("subtitle"),

    headerPanel(h3("Input data here", style = "color:navy")),

    # Sidebar panel 
    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( position =c("left"),
        sliderInput("SL",
                    "ServiceScore",
                    min = 1.28, max = 3.09, value = 2.28),

        numericInput("LT", "LT: weeks",0, min=0, max = 30),
        fileInput('file1', 'MS, choose xlsx file',
                  accept = c(".xlsx")
        ),

     br(),            
     actionButton("action_Calc", label = "Refresh & Calculate"), ),

    # Main panel
    mainPanel(h3( textOutput("SL"), 
               textOutput("LT"),
               textOutput("SS"),

               tableOutput('contents')
              ))))

     server <- function(input, output) {

    output$SL <- renderText({ 
        paste("Your score", input$SL)})
    output$LT <- renderText ({ 
        paste( "Your LT is", input$LT)})
    output$contents <- renderTable({

        req(input$file1)

        inFile <- input$file1

        read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
    })

    values<- reactiveValues()
    observe({
        input$action_Calc
        values$int<- isolate({
        input$SL*sqrt(input$LT/4)*sd(**HERE IS WHERE I NEED THE SD of the EXCEL FILE**)
        })})
     output$SS <- renderText({paste("calculation is", values$int)})


      }
     shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: "...standard deviation of an __Excel file__."??  You need to give R the name of a _variable_, not the name of a file.

Comment: sorry, that makes sense, the file is a single time series of numbers- hence the standard deviation of it. As the file is comprised of a single column, how would I code to reference the first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the Excel file in a reactive conductor:

```
Data <- reactive({
  req(input$file1)
  inFile <- input$file1
  read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
})

output$contents <- renderTable({
  Data()
})
```

Now if you want the standard deviation of the first column:

```
values<- reactiveValues()
observe({
  input$action_Calc
  values$int <- isolate({
    input$SL*sqrt(input$LT/4)*sd(Data()[[1]])
  })
})
output$SS <- renderText({paste("calculation is", values$int)})
```

Comment: thank you very much Stephane, this fixed my problem!